# Rubocop/Hound recommend freezing string literal class names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

My project uses HoundCI as a code linter, which I believe internally uses rubocop.

Recently I started noticing this sort of warning -

[image]

It appears on every class definition (e.g. `class User < ActiveRecord::Base`).

I understand the concept of freezing string literals, but why would it expect me to freeze class definitions? Also more importantly, how do I disable it? It's quite annoying to have 10+ of these "errors" polluting our pull requests.

Thank you!

**Edit:** Looks like it also started appearing on `require` statements that use string literals, like with rspec tests. This is definitely new and wasn't being flagged previously

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like Hound/Rubocop is detecting a violation of the [FrozenStringLiteralComment](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment) cop.

> This cop is designed to help upgrade to Ruby 3.0. It will add the comment `# frozen_string_literal: true` to the top of files to enable frozen string literals. Frozen string literals will be default in Ruby 3.0. The comment will be added below a shebang and encoding comment. The frozen string literal comment is only valid in Ruby 2.3+.

You can either add the magic comment manually to the top of your files

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

Or have Rubocop do it for you

```
$ bundle exec rubocop --auto-correct --only FrozenStringLiteralComment
```

You can also ignore the cop in your `rubocop.yml`, `Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment`

Comment: `--auto-correct` won't work here, as it is not save to correct them and may break code. You have to use  `--auto-correct-all`or `-A` to enforce this correction.